# fisheye formula of 3d world position to image space

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine

Can someone from the dev team or other can share the fish-eye formula between
single 3d position in world space or camera space
into final image coordinates. (image space).
as used in cycles.

thanks !

Comment: There is no one from the Blender Foundation on this Q&A site. Suggest you ask on https://developer.blender.org/

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to your question in the functions `direction_to_fisheye` and `fisheye_to_direction` in the Blender source code: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/intern/cycles/kernel/camera/projection.h. Even though the code talks about directions, I was able to use a version of these formulas to map 3D points from camera space to final image coordinates.